# WPF (XBAP) application not trusted on some machines butother get a prompt and can run the application

Tags: wpf, permissions, xbap

I'm having an Issue with a WPF file not running correctly.
On some machines it starts a security prompt shows up and clicking ok lets the application run fine.
but on other machines (some with an identical set up because the machines are all imaged the sames on this side of our network)  no security pop up, just "Trust not Granted" I've Placed a Log below. I've tried things including but not limted to, deplying it directly to iis, to a file location and moving it over,( all using  clickOnce) i have Fullpermissions checked, ive tried signed and unsigend, with passworded and unpassworded pfx.

I don't have the ability to modify the IE settings for the trusted sites and the like ( but I don't think thats the problem because the machines that work and the ones that son't should have the same set up)

I'd be greatful for any help. Thanks.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 5.1.2600.196608 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.239
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.239 (RTMGDR.030319-2300)
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://***.***.***.***/AutoData/AntiRoom/TestManagement.xbap
    Application url         : http://***.***.***.***/AutoData/AntiRoom/Application%20Files/TestManagement_1_0_0_25/TestManagement.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : TestManagement.xbap, Version=1.0.0.25, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=cbf2bb8ca25cd6ff, processorArchitecture=msil
    Application Identity        : TestManagement.exe, Version=1.0.0.25, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=cbf2bb8ca25cd6ff, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Online only application.
    * Browser-hosted application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * An exception occurred while determining trust. Following failure messages were detected:
        + User has refused to grant required permissions to the application.
    * An exception occurred while downloading the application. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The AssertApplicationRequirements method failed. The application cannot be committed.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    No phase information is available.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [01/03/2012 10:30:58 AM] System.Deployment.Application.TrustNotGrantedException (Unknown subtype)
        - User has refused to grant required permissions to the application.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationTrust.RequestTrust(SubscriptionState subState, Boolean isShellVisible, Boolean isUpdate, ActivationContext actCtx, TrustManagerContext tmc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrustCore(Boolean blocking, TrustParams tp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrust(TrustParams trustParams)
            at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.AssertApplicationRequirements(Boolean grantApplicationTrust)
            at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.AssertApplicationRequirements()
            at MS.Internal.AppModel.XappLauncherApp.AssertApplicationRequirementsAsync(Object unused)
    * [01/03/2012 10:30:58 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (Unknown subtype)
        - The AssertApplicationRequirements method failed. The application cannot be committed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.WaitForAssertApplicationRequirements()
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeCore(Boolean blocking)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeAsyncWorker()

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the script I use to make all XBAPs on our internal network run as Full Trust. Usually I place this in a batch file and send users the link to the .bat if they email me about Full Trust errors

```
%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CasPol -q -machine -addgroup All_Code -url http://InternalWebServer/* FullTrust -n XBAPSecurity -polchgprompt off
```

Just replace where it says `InternalWebServer` with whatever your internal web server root is

Comment: It's worth noting this must be run as Admin (elevated) where UAC is enabled.