# xbap not opening , giving trust error

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xbap

while i am running xbap direcly in IE, its running perfectly,
and when i am opining in iframe its giving trust not provide error,
error description given below

PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.3.9600.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 2.0.50727.8009
    System.Deployment.dll       : 2.0.50727.8012 (FX35W81RTMGDR.050727-8000)
    mscorwks.dll            : 2.0.50727.8009 (FX35W81RTMGDR.050727-8000)
    dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://localhost:59169/mypath/WpfBrowserApplication1.xbap
    Application url         : http://localhost:mypath/WpfBrowserApplication1_1_0_0_78/WpfBrowserApplication1.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : WpfBrowserApplication1.xbap, Version=1.0.0.78, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21728584691eaf20, processorArchitecture=msil
    Application Identity        : WpfBrowserApplication1.exe, Version=1.0.0.78, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21728584691eaf20, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Online only application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.   * Browser-hosted application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * An exception occurred while determining trust. Following failure messages were detected:
        + User has refused to grant required permissions to the application.
    * An exception occurred while downloading the application. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The AssertApplicationRequirements method failed. The application cannot be committed.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    No phase information is available.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [8/24/2015 9:46:25 PM] System.Deployment.Application.TrustNotGrantedException (Unknown subtype)
        - User has refused to grant required permissions to the application.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationTrust.RequestTrust(SubscriptionState subState, Boolean isShellVisible, Boolean isUpdate, ActivationContext actCtx, TrustManagerContext tmc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrustCore(Boolean blocking, TrustParams tp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrust(TrustParams trustParams)
            at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.AssertApplicationRequirements(Boolean grantApplicationTrust)
            at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.AssertApplicationRequirements()
            at MS.Internal.AppModel.XappLauncherApp.AssertApplicationRequirementsAsync(Object unused)
    * [8/24/2015 9:46:25 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (Unknown subtype)
        - The AssertApplicationRequirements method failed. The application cannot be committed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.WaitForAssertApplicationRequirements()
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeCore(Boolean blocking)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeAsyncWorker()

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://www.bing.com/search?q=xbap%20user%20has%20refused%20to%20grant%20required%20permissions%20to%20the%20application) search seems to pull up a load of results. The second one points [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714981/wpf-xbap-application-not-trusted-on-some-machines-butother-get-a-prompt-and-ca), which sounds like a possible, but there are a few to choose from....

Comment: dear thanks for reply,my issue resolved by answer given given above thanks
...kindly check this thread, and help if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678122/how-to-open-xbap-in-firefox-39-0-chrome-in-windows-8-1-pro-64bit

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

upgrade framework and

- Go to your project properties page, select the 'Signing' tab
- Make sure "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" is checked -> Click the 'More details...' button
- Click 'Install Certificate' (if you cant see this button, just delete your old pfx-file from solution explorer and then click Create Test Certificate) -> press Next to get past the Wizard-intro -> Check the 'Place all certificates in the following store'-radiobutton -> Click 'Browse...'
- Select Trusted Root Certification Authorities and press OK
- Press Next and then Finish to complete the wizard and do it again but install it to Trushed Publishers instead

No more security prompts while developing!